# Save and load files from Tkinter buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, config

I am trying to figure out how to save settings but I'm stumped on how to.

I trying to save a scale, checkbox, and a optionmenu and be able to save to a file then load that file to save your settings after you close the program.

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("config test")
root.geometry("500x500")

b4 =IntVar()
b5 =IntVar()
we =IntVar()


checkbutton1 = Checkbutton(root, text="test1", variable=b4, onvalue=35564533,offvalue=35456533).grid(row=0, column=0)
checkbutton2 = Checkbutton(root, text="test2", variable=b5, onvalue=35456533,offvalue=35564533).grid(row=0, column=1)

ma3r = StringVar(root)
ma3r.set("Normal")
r = OptionMenu(root, ma3r, "test1", "test2", "test3").grid(row=2,column=0)
Scal = Scale(root, from_=-100, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL, variable=we).grid(row=1, column=0)

mar = StringVar(root)
mar.set("CFG1")
w = OptionMenu(root, mar, "CFG1", "CFG2", "CFG3").grid(row=3,column=0)


butto = Button(root, text="save CFG").grid(row=4,column=0)
butto = Button(root, text="load CFG").grid(row=5,column=0)

mainloop()
```

Comment: For starters, you will want to add `command=` parameter into your buttons to do anything with them. Alternatively, maybe you should start with what it means to "load" something because it seems everything is hard-coded, and you can hard-code a "config file" to start with rather than needing to save anything from the GUI... What are you trying to load data into?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am trying to load from a already saved config file so it can set the widgets to what was saved on the config file. Sorry if i didnt answer your question right im still learning.

Comment: Okay, so if you already have a file, then you'll need to `open()` it, but that seems to be missing from your code. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: @OneCricketeer no sir i have not tried that yet, but i am trying to make it save a config with the settings that be able to load.

Comment: I understand that. I suggest you focus on one problem at a time. If you start with loading of the file, then your save will be easier because you will already know what format the file-contents need to be in

Comment: I don't see any code that attempts to load or save anything.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing an [example from online](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-stringvar/), you can easily add an update function from it.

config.json

`{"title":"config test"}`

main.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import json

class App(tk.Tk):
    DEFAULT_TITLE = 'config test'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.config = dict()
        with open('config.json') as f:
          self.config = json.load(f)
       
        self.title(self.config.get('title', DEFAULT_TITLE))
        self.geometry("300x80")

        self.name_var = tk.StringVar()

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        padding = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}
        # label
        ttk.Label(self, text='Name:').grid(column=0, row=0, **padding)

        # Entry
        name_entry = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.name_var)
        name_entry.grid(column=1, row=0, **padding)
        name_entry.focus()

        # Button
        submit_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Submit', command=self.submit)
        submit_button.grid(column=2, row=0, **padding)

    def submit(self):
        """ Save the details into the config """
        self.config['title'] = self.name_var.get()
        with open('config.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self.config, f)
        self.load()  # reload the GUI

    def load(self):
        self.title(self.config.get('title', DEFAULT_TITLE))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

[image]

```
$ cat config.json
{"title": "Updated name"}
```

---

To update an OptionMenu, you'd have a list, then you "splat it"

```
# your options
options = ['1', '2', '3']
# the name to display and its value
v = tk.StringVar()
v.set(options[0])
# defining the widget
menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, v, *options)

... 
# setting new options to existing menu
new_options = ['4', '5', '6']
menu.set_menu(default=None, *new_options)
```

To get an event when you select something in the menu [see this example](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-optionmenu/)

Site also has slider and checkbox examples...

---

In general, using the submit button to save would be easiest, but if you make a lot of changes frequently, it'd be better to have each command handler update the file directly rather than wait for the button click

Answer (score 0):

Using `import configparser`. It will be saved to file , and then loaded on fly.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import configparser

parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
parser.read('config.ini')

root = Tk()
root.title("config test")
root.geometry("500x500")

 
b4 = IntVar()
checkbutton1 = Checkbutton(root, text="test1", variable=b4).grid(row=0, column=0)
r = parser.get('User', 'b4')
b4.set(r) 

b5 = IntVar()
checkbutton2 = Checkbutton(root, text="test2", variable=b5).grid(row=0, column=1)
r = parser.get('User', 'b5')
b5.set(r)

ma3r = StringVar(root)
ma3r.set("Normal")
r = OptionMenu(root, ma3r, "test1", "test2", "test3").grid(row=2,column=0) 
r = parser.get('User', 'ma3r')
ma3r.set(r)

mar = StringVar(root)
mar.set("CFG1")
w = OptionMenu(root, mar, "CFG1", "CFG2", "CFG3").grid(row=3,column=0)
r = parser.get('User', 'mar')
mar.set(r)

we =IntVar()
Scal = Scale(root, from_=-100, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL, variable=we)
Scal.grid(row=1, column=0)
 
def Load_file():...
     
       
def user_settings():
    if not parser.has_section("User"):
        parser.add_section('User')
     
    parser.set('User', 'b4', str(b4.get()))
    parser.set('User', 'b5', str(b5.get()))
    parser.set('User', 'ma3r', str(ma3r.get()))
    parser.set('User', 'mar', str(mar.get()))
    
    with open("config.ini", "w") as config:
        parser.write(config)

btn1 = Button(root, text="save CFG", command=user_settings).grid(row=4,column=0)
btn2 = Button(root, text="load CFG").grid(row=5,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Output: save to file and load on fly.

[image]

Edit: copy and paste in notepad and save as config.ini:

```
[User]
b4 = 1
b5 = 1
ma3r = test3
mar = CFG3
scal = 53
```